# API body Request Error

Tags: php, api, php-curl

I am working on API where in my json body request the body URL is correct and when I trigger it the body URL is showing me some other format. Please find the below code.

```
$url12="http://domainverify.com/api.php";
$para='Name='.$name.'&Phone_number='.$mobile.'&City='.$emailid.'&Age='.$age.'&Occupation='.$occupation.'';

$ch = curl_init($url1);

$data['url'] = "$url12?$para";

echo "<pre>";

print_r($data);

$payload = json_encode($data);

echo $payload;
```

And the output from `print_r` is:

```
(
    [url] => http://domainverify.com/api.php?Name=Ritesh&Phone_number=7019373695&City=bangalore&Age=29&Occupation=salaried
)
```

But `json_encode` gives me this and adds extra backslashes to the url:

```
{"url":"http:\/\/domainverify.com\/api.php?Name=Ritesh&Phone_number=7019373695&City=bangalore&Age=29&Occupation=salaried"}
```

SO can you help me regrading this.

Comment: What format do you expect to see?  You are getting exactly what you're requesting.

Comment: Hi the format should be like this "http://domainverify.com/api.php" but in body URL it shows like this "http:\/\/domainverify.com\/api.php" so for that my API is not working if i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need the exact same output you should use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag:

```
$payload = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

This prevents your URL to be escaped.